# How to get the height of UITableViewCell in iOS 8 with new auto sizing feature and AutoLayout?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am programming for iOS 8. There is the new feature - **auto sizing** `UITableViewCells` (more info [here](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells)). It works fine. But I want to know the **height of some cell**.

So, supposing new **auto sizing feature calculated the height** of cell. I have `NSIndexPath` and **I want to know calculated height** of this cell. Is there any method or way to get it?

PS I am using autolayout.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the contentView (UIView class) from the cell and get his height.

Comment: `contentSize` is only `UIScrollView's` property. I can't get it from the `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Sorry  I was thinking contentview and writed contentsize. Get the contentview of the cell and get the height

Comment: How about checking it in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` ?  Maybe by that time the height has already been calculated.

Comment: That works! I placed checking `cell.contentView.frame.size.height` to `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and it worked! Thank you guys!